# “Page not found. What’s worse, a hilarious 404 page can’t be found either.”

Tags: http-status-code-404

My file structure is:

User/me/www/Craft-2.3.2644/
I am using MAMP and MAMP Points to this folder as my 'server root'.

Everything inside and including my web root has 777 permissions.

Inside this folder are three items:

craft/
public/
readme.txt
I have a MySQL database:

Domain: localhost
User: root
I have pointed the db.php file to my server, with 'root' as the password.

My index.php file in my public folder points to ../craft which reroutes to /app/index.php (a file that does exist in that location).

The most positive result I can get when surfing to localhost/public/index.php is a message that reads as below...

Page not found

What’s worse, a hilarious 404 page can’t be found either.
With any other permissions I cannot access the folder because I'm not allowed (oops message).

And with any other mapping in the index file I receive a message:

File not found